# Add a link inside a div window

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe, xmp

How can I add a link inside a "popup" window. When I use href it makes the entire div dissapear. Here is the code. Thanks.

```
<div class="listing" style="display:none" id="open_window2_codediv">
      <xmp id="open_window2" class="listing" >
var win = new Window({className: "dialog",  width:500, height:400, zIndex: 100, resizable:       
true, title: "Main Menu", showEffect:Effect.BlindDown, hideEffect: Effect.SwitchOff, draggable:true, wiredDrag: true})

win.getContent().innerHTML= "<div style='padding:10px'> LINK HERE!!!!!</div>"
win.setStatusBar("Menu bar info");
win.showCenter();        
<xmp>        
<div>
```

Comment: Your code is incorrect. You should close the `<div>` & `<xmp>` with `</div>` & `</xmp>`.

Comment: I took it out when I posted the code... But in the real code it is correct.

Comment: The browser is able to display the page, but it does NOT imply that the codes are correct.

Comment: You want to change the link within the open window?  Is that an Adobe flash window or something?

Comment: I just want to create a link within this code that refreshes the "parent" window. A standard a href does not work. It negates the popup div and shows nothing. There has to be a way im sure. I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `window.open`

```
var win = window.open();
win.document.childNodes[0].innerHTML = 
    "<div style='padding:10px'><a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a></div>";
```

Having said that, **this is <strike>probably</strike> a very, very bad idea**.  `window.open` is supposed to work with a url.  You should put the html you want your popup window to contain into a separate html file, then call

```
window.open('yourFile.htm');
```

The [MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) lists all of the options that this function accepts.

Comment: Sorta, but I have more than one link on the popup. there for I need to nest many links within that snippet of code and I cant figure out why it doenst work.

Comment: @user1086253 - create whatever html structure you need, put it in a php/aspx/html file, and call that by url from window.open

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't work :(. The link may work but the popup no longer does.

Comment: @user1086253 - do you have popup blocker turned on?